# Storing data as html within json or as json data fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I have some content that needs to be rendered as HTML, what would be considered best practice in terms of how the content is stored in ElasticSearch:

1) Store the HTML inside a single json field

2) Store the content as individual data fields, using nested objects with additional fields to indicate whether it is a list or a table etc and then generate html from this

Just for info I am going to be using elasticsearch to serve the content and generate the entire UI from the data stored in the index.

Answer (score 0):

I would clearly go with option 2 as it's more flexible and you don't clutter your ES with plenty of HTML.

Then I would give a shot at the [Elasticsearch view plugin](https://github.com/tlrx/elasticsearch-view-plugin) to generate the HTML views out of my documents.

There is a comprehensive example [available here](http://tlrx.github.io/elasticsearch-view-plugin)